# Play Billing Library is missing developerPayload

Tags: android, google-play, play-billing-library

I'm planning to migrate to Play Billing Library, but there is absent developerPayload. It was very useful for validating on server side with additional information. Are there any other ways to add developerPayload to purchase?

UPDATE: I found another way to validate:
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingFlowParams.Builder#setObfuscatedAccountId(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

The `developerPayload` is not included in the Google Play Billing Library.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63381481

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/issues/78

The Google Play server API will verify that the purchase was processed by Google.

If your server needs to verify the authenticity of the client app (when you send the `purchaseToken` to the server), you can send extra information from the client app.

Comment: If 'developerPayload' is not there, how do we find out which user renewed the subscription when I receive the Real-time developer notification upon successful/failed renewals? I have the purchase token, and order ID but with those two things, I can't find the corresponding user in my database.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Chris said you can use my own fork of the Play Billing Library with support of the developerPayload https://github.com/DimaDake/billing

```
BillingFlowParams flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                        .setSku("inapp_1")
                        .setType(SkuType.INAPP)
                        .setDeveloperPayload("your_custom_developer_payload")
                        .build();
int responseCode = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(MainActivity.this, flowParams);
```